# C# lack of colision in simple 2D game using ref in method

Tags: c#, graphics2d

I try to creat 2D mario style game. Everything worked until I started make it more 'objective'.Mario doesn't stop on end of window -  stops but after while goes across window. If I make method without ref, mario even doesnt stop on while.

Mario class

```
class Mario: System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
{
    public Mario(int x, int y)
    {
        Image = Image.FromFile("Mario.png");
        Location = new Point(x, y);
        Size = new Size(16, 32);
        SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        TabIndex = 0;
        TabStop = false;
    }
public void colision( System.Windows.Forms.Panel s,ref bool l, ref bool r)
    {
        if (this.Right > s.Right) { r = false; }

        if (this.Left < s.Left) {  l = false;  }
    }

}
```

Main class - Form1

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    bool right=false,left=false;

public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        player.Top = screen.Height - player.Height;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(right== true) { player.Left += 1; }
        if (left == true) { player.Left -=1; }

       player.colision(screen, ref left, ref right);
}
```

screen is System.Windows.Forms.Panel and player is Mario Type which were initialized in form1.Designer.cs

I deleted irrelevant field and methods.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:graphics2d]?

Comment: debugger is your best friend. learn how to use it to find out where is your problem :p

Comment: program goes into if condition.

Answer (score 1):

The location of a control is relative to it's parent - if you place your `Mario` at `(0, 0)`, it won't appear at the top-left corner of your *screen* or *form*, but at the top-left corner of the `Panel` - its direct parent.

Similarly, the location of that `Panel` is also relative to its parent.

Let's assume your `Panel` is positioned in your form at `(100, 100)` and its size is `(400, 300)` - this would mean its `Left` property is `100` and its `Right` property is `500` - `Mario` will be out of sight for those 100 pixels.

So your check should be:

```
if (this.Right > s.Width) { r = false; }
if (this.Left < 0) {  l = false;  }
```

You already did the right thing with the vertical placement (by using `Height` instead of `Bottom`):

```
player.Top = screen.Height - player.Height;
```